# How to get the controller execution time using interceptor and inject it in bean to display in json format

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring and I am very new to Interceptors. Right now I am capturing each request execution time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` in my controller, setting the execution time in a bean and returning that bean to display in JSON format.

Now i want to use Interceptors to aid my application for such functionality. I tested some example but `postHandle(..)` and `afterCompletion()` are called after the bean value was returned from the controller and I am unable to set `executionTime`.

Here below is my sample bean properties:

```
private String status;
private Long executionTime;
private String message;
private String id;
```

Requesting you to kindly suggest me right direction to do this. Thanks!

Comment: how do you set values? Show us the code

Comment: long exeTime = endTime-StartTime; sampleBeanObj.setExecutionTime(exeTime); These code was in my controller. Now i want that interceptor calculate the request execution time and somehow give help me that time value in bean because i am rendering bean as a json format on display screen.Thanks.

Comment: I mean where do you place this code inside interceptor?

Comment: Please check below interceptor code and try to understand my basic requirement. I want to use interceptor for getting controller request execution time and then i need to bind this value with name qTime, who else is using my rest API. Only what i need to do is Exposing rest api with one parameter qTime={} that will show rest client user the time taken. Now please help me in how i can do that using Interceptor. My response format is Json.

Answer (score 0):

In your current requirement,  Calculating Method execution time is your **cross cutting concern**.

So using Spring AOP will be useful, 
Use **Around Advice** from AOP API.

Around advice is the most powerful advice in Spring AOP. The reason is, this advice can perform custom behavior before and after the method invocation .

I refer you the below link to have look.

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/05/spring-aop-around-advice-example.html#.U1efO6IUBCw

Comment: Thanks a lot Pramod, shared link is useful but it is realted to adding aspect to a method. As we know by Interceptor can hook event on controller request and it saves us for add all methods name. Can we do some thing like with AOP to call upon every controller request?